# How to extract text data from an element that is inside another element with xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I have data like:

```
<div>
  <a rel="nofollow" class="someclass " href="www.example.com">
    <span id="name" title="Title of interest>
      <b class="highlight">Other test</b>
      <b class="highlight">Moretext</b> 
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Edit: I have tried:

`response.xpath('//div/a/span[@title]')`,this however returns an empty list for some reason.

I also tried :
`response.css('div.a.span')` and the result is the same.

The closest i have gotten is simply :
`response.xpath('//div//span')`,undoubtedly this returns the desired result....AMONG OTHER THINGS..which is not exactly what im looking for

I'm trying to get the title attribute of the span element.Id like to know how i can do it with xpath or css selectors.

I'm using python 3 and scrapy btw.

Comment: What have you tried? Please add some info about why you can't get it to work yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like this?

CSS:

```
response.css('#name::attr(title)').extract()
```

XPath:

```
response.xpath('span[@id="name"]/@title')
```

Now, this does not take into account that the element "is inside another element". In this case, we do not need the surrounding elements, because the HTML standard states, that the `id` attribute value must be unique on the whole HTML page.

However, if you have other situations where you need to query for multiple element hierarchies, you can just nest them with spaces in CSS and with slashes in XPath.

CSS:

```
response.css('div a #name::attr(title)').extract()
```

XPath:

```
# // means "anywhere in the hierarchy in Xpath
response.xpath('//div/a/span[@id="name"]/@title')
```

I recommend you to read some XPath tutorial and some tutorial on CSS Selectors. They are both quite simple.

### Your existing CSS selector

Your CSS selector `response.css('div.a.span')` is wrong. In CSS a dot means `class` and multiple dots mean multiple classes, so this selector would search for a `div` tag with class `a` and class `span`, i.e.

```
<div class="a span">sample</div>
```

The correct CSS selector would be

```
response.css('div a span::attr(title)')
```

(if your framework does support the `attr` notation, which scrapy does).

### Your existing XPath selector

`response.xpath('//div/a/span[@title]')` should be correct actually, you can verify this with one of the xpath testers available online (e.g. [codebeautify Xpath-Tester](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)). You will have to sanitize your code before, because your title attribute lacks an ending quotation mark and thus is not valid XML.

If this is exactly your original code including the missing quotation mark, maybe this is the problem. Online XPath engines usually won't parse it, because they require valid XML. Scrapy will parse it, because it also parses HTML and dirty HTML, but it could result in a different DOM tree. You might want to fiddle around with the scrapy console a bit and check different selector hierarchies like `//span[@title]`, `//div/a`, `//div/a/span` etc. to see what happens.

`response.xpath('//div//span')` is indeed very broad, it will find all `span` that follow a `div` at any level of descendancy.

Comment: ,i already tried that xpath expression but it returns an empty list,also the data is quite extensive and as you might imagine,the `id`s are different for all the span tags so i cant use the `id` to identify the content im trying to scrape here

Comment: I added some updates to your existing selectors. I think the XPath selector that yielded 0 results should be right (after I fixed the XML error in your pasted code). So, the problem with the XPath selector should be somewhere else. Either the errors in the source code lead to another DOM tree or something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of info on the css selectors however despite all the efforts,i still cannot get to the span tag.Even `#quickLookItem-1 > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)` doesn't work.`response.xpath('//div/a')`doesnt even return the span tags.Thanks for the efforts though

Comment: Scratch that last comment,`response.css('#quickLookItem-1 > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')
`  actually worked,again thanks for your time